# Why does shelve.sync not work as expected?

Tags: python, shelve

Why doesn't `shelve` sync the second key (`world`) in the below example? I am calling the `sync` method twice to update the data - but it doesn't do it - nor does it raise an exception. Is this an expected behavior? In general, can I rely on the sync to happen **always**?

I was evaluating `shelve` as an option to reduce the loading time of my "in-memory" application by saving the state (a deeply-nested object) of my application.

Also, does anyone know what is the time complexity of `shelve.sync`? Is it `O(delta)` where `detla` is the *changes* that happened to the deeply-nested object?

```
import shelve

example = {}

d = shelve.open("shelve.db", writeback=True)
d["example"] = example

example["hello"] = "hello"
d.sync()
example["world"] = "world"
d.sync()

d.close()

d = shelve.open("shelve.db", writeback=True)
print(d["example"]["hello"])
print(d["example"]["world"])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `writeback=True` shelf has a cache that stores objects retrieved from the cache. Elements retrieved twice are retrieved from the cache, and the cache is used to write changes back to the file when the shelf is closed or synced.

`Shelf.sync()` writes all cache entries back to the file on disk, and **clears the cache**. The shelf forgets about all objects retrieved. Further changes to `example` will not be reflected in the shelf, and if you try to retrieve `d["example"]` again after the sync, you will get a new dict reconstructed from the shelf, rather than getting `example`.

It doesn't look like there's a public interface to sync changes without flushing the cache.

---

Also, `sync` re-pickles every entry in the cache, regardless of what has or hasn't changed (it has no idea), and writes the new pickles back to disk. It takes however long that takes.

Comment: Thanks, now when I inspect the `id` of the element it makes sense. Both are different objects! Feels a bit non-intuitive though.